# Hiow to switch Infopath view in XMLFormView Webpart when the Web Part loads?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am using the code given at following link : [How To: Display browser enabled InfoPath forms in a web part supporting connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2007/05/08/display-browser-enabled-infopath-forms-in-a-web-part.aspx) in my custom web part.

Does any one know how to switch the Infopath view to a specific View when the web part loads ?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

The following InfoPath code would generally work when using the InfoPath client.

```
public void FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)
{
    e.SetDefaultView("View 2");
}
```

Not sure if this will do the same in Browser Enabled forms.

The beta of the PDF Converter for SharePoint I have worked on comes with a version of the Browser based InfoPath viewer that allows the view name to be passed on the URL. [See this post for an example](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/using-sharepoint-forms-services-to.html).